# Create New Contact with Sub-Type Brings Up Wrong Custom Field Sets

Tags: core

As of v5.69 (maybe earlier, not sure), whenever we go to "Contacts / Create Individual / Create " to create one of our sub-types, the wrong set of custom fields show up for that type in the contact create window. It's like it's bringing up some default set of custom fields instead of the custom fields linked to that contact type.

If, instead, we just use "Contacts / Create Individual" and then fill out the Contact Type field in that create window, it then properly refreshes the window with the right custom fields.

So it must be something with the call that includes the sub-type that causes this issue. The URL when we try to create a sub-type specific individual is something like this:
https://example.org/civicrm/contact/add?ct=Individual&cst=Facilitator&reset=1

I don't know if I should create an issue tracker for this or if it's just our setup. Is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Can you reproduce that on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ ?

Comment: @Aidan, yes, I just reproduced it on the demo. I added a custom field set for Students. I then tried Contact / Create / Individual / Student and the new custom field set did not show up. I then removed the sub-type of Student from create window field, and put it back in again, and the custom field set showed up. So it's happening when a sub-type is sent via the URL.

Comment: Great - in that case, please create an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/new

Comment: In case anyone else is tracking this, here is the new issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4910

Comment: The fix has been merged and will be in a future release but you make the change manually to your site now: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29003/files